# Oracle APEX: Dynamic SetValue is not working

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

On Page Load I need to set a value of page item P1_ITEM2 based on the value of the application item APP_ITEM1

I created the following DA on page load:

```
Action: SetValue

Set Type: PL/SQL Expression 

PL/SQL Expression: package1.my_function(:APP_ITEM1)

Items to submit: APP_ITEM1

Affected Elements
Selection type: Items
Items: P1_ITEM2
```

Nothing gets set. Not sure what is going on

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?,  just trying to set :P1_ITEM2 := :APP_ITEM1;  ?   There are several things that could be done, but looks like u want to do something else.

Comment: Any reason not using a process on page load, instead of having the web client invoke another server side event after the page is rendered?

Comment: Why don't you just use a computation in a pre-rendering process point instead of dynamic action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an After Header Computation for the page item.(In your case P1_ITEM2)
2. Select the Type as Function Body and paste your function call (In your case package1.my_function(:APP_ITEM1))